# How a single $p_x$ orbital transform under $C_{4v}$ point group?

Tags: atomic-physics, group-theory, representation-theory, orbitals

How a single $p_x$ atomic orbital transform under $C_{4v}$ point group?

---

**Background**
I'm trying to understand how atomic orbitals hybridize on a lattice plane, e.g. NaCl (111) plane. For this purpose, I firstly find the point group that leaves the lattice plane invariant, for example $C_{4v}$. Then, the atomic orbitals ($p_x$, $d_{xy}$ ...) parallel to the lattice plane are considered, and I ask the question:

**Under $C_{4v}$ point group (determined only considering how lattice points arrange), can $p_x$, $d_{xy}$ hybridize?**

Is this the correct question to ask? Since when atomic orbitals come in, the actual point group may become a subgroup of $C_{4v}$.

---

From the character table of $C_{4v}$ point group, I learned that $(p_x,p_y)$ corresponds to a 2-dimensional irreducible representation E in $C_{4v}$. However, in my case of analyzing coupling bewteen atomic orbitals, there is only one $p_x$ orbital to be transformed under $C_{4v}$ point group, as illustrated in the figure below

[image]

How does this $p_x$ orbital transform? For example, the $\sigma_d$ transforms $p_x$ into $p_y$, then what should the character of $\sigma_d$ be? Is it zero since $p_y$ is orthogonal to $p_x$?

Moreover, if $p_x$ as a 1-dimensional function actually transforms like E in $C_{4v}$, then can it couple with a linear combination of $(p_x,p_y)$?

Comment: something's not right.  If $p_x$ is a basis state for a 2-dimensional irrep of $C_{4v}$, then it's not a 1d function in $C_{4v}$.  In other words, a single $p_x$ does not always transform to itself under $C_{4v}$.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Do you mean the underlying point group is in fact not $C_{4v}$, since $p_x$ is a 1d function in this case?

Comment: no I mean $p_x$ is not 1d, OR your group is not $C_{4v}$.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Thanks. The $C_{4v}$ is the point group that leaves a lattice plane invariant, and at this point, the atomic orbitals are not considered. Then, the atomic orbitals parallel to the lattice plane are taken into account, and $p_x$ is just one of the orbitals, so is it correct to ask "how a $p_x$ orbital transform under $C_{4v}$ point group"?

Comment: yes (cute example in fact) but it does not transform by a 1d irrep.